# sed regex with '+' doesn't work - why?

Tags: linux, regex, sed

I don't understand it. I'd like to replace the `ip-up 9490:notify_rc` string to `ip-up ****:notify_rc`. I thought it's simple:

```
echo "ip-up 9490:notify_rc" | sed -e 's/ip-up [0-9]+:notify_rc/ip-up ****:notify_rc/'
```

but no, it doesn't work for me, the output is `ip-up 9490:notify_rc`. Why? How can I do it?

Instead of `[0-9]+` I've tried: `\S+ [:num:]+` etc., tried to add `-r` switch to `sed` command, without success. The result is the original string every time.

If I change `+` to `*`, then it becomes working; but what's wrong with plus sign?

**Update**
Here is a short sample:

```
echo "ip-up 9490:notify_rc" | sed -e 's/ip-up [0-9]+:notify_rc/ip-up ****:notify_rc/' 
ip-up 9490:notify_rc
echo "ip-up 9490:notify_rc" | sed -e 's/ip-up [0-9]+:notify_rc/ip-up ****:notify_rc/' -r
ip-up 9490:notify_rc
echo "ip-up 9490:notify_rc" | sed -e 's/ip-up [0-9]+:notify_rc/ip-up ****:notify_rc/' -E
ip-up 9490:notify_rc

sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jay Fenlason, Tom Lord, Ken Pizzini,
and Paolo Bonzini.
GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put anything (except the `sed` script) after the -e switch.

```
$ echo "ip-up 9490:notify_rc" | sed -r -e 's/ip-up [0-9]+:notify_rc/ip-up ****:notify_rc/'
ip-up ****:notify_rc
```

Comment: This is not typical of GNU programs (AFAIK), but you're right... Hmmm... how can I accept both of good answers?

Answer (score 3):

You're hitting the difference between regular expression and *extended* regular expression.

The one or more operator is `+` in extended regular expression. You can tell `sed` that the regex is an extended one using the option `-r` or `-E`.

```
echo "ip-up 9490:notify_rc" | sed -r -e 's/ip-up [0-9]+:notify_rc/ip-up ****:notify_rc/'
```

If you use (basic) regular expression, you need to escape that operator such it is not taken as a character.

```
echo "ip-up 9490:notify_rc" | sed -e 's/ip-up [0-9]\+:notify_rc/ip-up ****:notify_rc/'
```

Comment: O.K., but I've tried it with -r switch, and it didn't work.

Comment: @deadcandidate Are you using GNU sed? I guess not. Try using `-E` instead.

Comment: oliv  see the update at the end of the post

Answer (score 0):

If there are no ohter numbers in the string to preserve you can use the following syntax:

```
sed -e "s/[0-9]/\*/g"
```

This will replace any number with an asterisk.